# Is a django annotate call lazy?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Django QuerySets are lazy and not evaluated until they are needed. Is this true for [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) as well?

Comment: `.annotate(..)` is lazy in the sense that the queryset still is not evaluated. But when the queryset is evaluated it is *with* the annotations, since the annotates are part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Unlike aggregate(), annotate() is not a terminal clause. The output of the annotate() clause is a QuerySet; this QuerySet can be modified using any other QuerySet operation, including filter(), order_by(), or even additional calls to annotate().

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset